# vs 2017 c++ string gives numbers

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli, character

I have a problem with "my_txt" as a label in Visual Studio 2017. It gives me a series of numbers instead of random characters. I want to add random character in my string each time. This is my code:

```
    String ^ my_str = ""; 
    static const char random_chars[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    if (digit_check == false) {
        my_txt->Text = L"error";
    }
    else {

        for (int i = 0; i < max_digit; i++) {
            my_txt->Text = "";
            next_char[i] = random_chars[rand() % (sizeof(random_chars) - 1)];

            my_str +=  next_char[i];
        }

        my_txt->Text = my_str;
    }
```

Thank you.

PS: "next_char" is defined above ("char next_char[max];")

Comment: This is not C++ code, the question should not have the C++ tag.  It looks like C++/CX or C++/CLI code, which are both separate languages from C++, with an unfortunate names that causes confusion.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Answer (score 0):

Note in one branch you do: `my_txt->Text = L"error"` which leads one to believe you're Text expects a wide string. In your case `next_char` and `random_chars` are single byte wide strings. you can change them to `wchar_t` to fix this issue.